# phpmyadmin in ubuntu xampp can not login after flush privileges

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed xampp in my ubunut 16.04 vps. It was running nicely with phpmyadmin. all of a sudden I can not login my phpmyadmin with root user. It just refused and give me the painful error which can not solve. the error is:

```html
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I can login with phpmyadmin supercontrol user... but the super user does not have any access to mysql.user table.

then I add "**skip-grant-tables**"  to **/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf** file and login with root user . Now I cant set the root user's password anyway.

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to get rid of this situation? thanks in advance

Comment: that soinds more like a problem with the databases aor table, try to CHECK them and have a backup ready

Comment: no... my database and tables are ok... i can login via phpmyadmin supercontrol user.. I just can not set any grant prvileges in user tables

Comment: you set during the install 2 passwords one for the server and one for phpmyadmin, so whan you change your privleges at mysql you can't access the database, because phpmyadmin can't connect to the server. phpmyadmin has its own user managemment. sopost what ypu excatly have doen to teh user root, or show us what grant it has now